# Unable to authenticate Flutter app using SignalR [ABP]

Tags: c#, flutter, signalr, abp

I'm encountering an authentication problem while attempting to connect a Flutter app to SignalR. The backend server correctly receives the token, but the connection to the hub sets isAuthenticated to false. I've tried various approaches without success. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Package used**

- signalr_netcore:
  git:
  url: https://github.com/geekz-reno/signalr_client.git
  ref: master

**flutter doctor -v:**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 3.16.0-5.0.pre.15, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2283], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.16.0-5.0.pre.15 on channel master at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision fe0275f9d5 (22 hours ago), 2023-10-05 05:57:26 -0400
    • Engine revision f8d53c5fe9
    • Dart version 3.2.0 (build 3.2.0-231.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.28.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\muonroi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-33-ext5, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 17.6.5)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise
    • Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 version 17.6.33829.357
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)

[√] VS Code (version 1.83.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\muonroi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.74.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)                  • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2283]
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 117.0.5938.134
    • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 117.0.2045.47

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

**Code connect to hub**

```
// Flutter code to connect to the hub
await _initSharedPreferences();
_hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(
        SignalrCentral.chatStatus,
        options: HttpConnectionOptions(
            accessTokenFactory: () async {
                return _sharedPreferences
                    .getString(KeyToken.accessToken.name)!;
            },
            headers: SignalrCentral.getHeader(
                _sharedPreferences.getString(KeyToken.encToken.name)!)))
    .withAutomaticReconnect(retryDelays: [30000])
    .build();
await initHubAndListenStatus();

Future<void> initHubAndListenStatus() async {
    try {
        await _hubConnection.start();
        debugPrint('Connection established successfully');
    } catch (e) {
        print('Error starting hub connection: $e');
    }
}
```

**Code backend server**

````
/* This method is needed to authorize SignalR javascript client.
         * SignalR can not send authorization header. So, we are getting it from query string as an encrypted text. */
        private static Task QueryStringTokenResolver(MessageReceivedContext context)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/signalr"))
            {
                var env = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
                var config = env.GetAppConfiguration();
                var allowAnonymousSignalRConnection = bool.Parse(config["App:AllowAnonymousSignalRConnection"]);

                return SetToken(context, allowAnonymousSignalRConnection);
            }

            List<string> urlsUsingEnchAuthToken = new List<string>()
            {
                "/Chat/GetUploadedObject?",
                "/Profile/GetProfilePictureByUser?"
            };

            if (urlsUsingEnchAuthToken.Any(url => context.HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl().Contains(url)))
            {
                if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("authorization"))
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }

                return SetToken(context, false);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }


        private static Task SetToken(MessageReceivedContext context, bool allowAnonymous)
        {
            var qsAuthToken = context.HttpContext.Request.Query["enc_auth_token"].FirstOrDefault() ?? context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["enc_auth_token"].FirstOrDefault();
            if (qsAuthToken == null)
            {
                if (!allowAnonymous)
                {
                    throw new AbpAuthorizationException("SignalR auth token is missing.");
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            //Set auth token from cookie
            context.Token = SimpleStringCipher.Instance.Decrypt(qsAuthToken, AppConsts.DefaultPassPhrase);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue when sending additional parameters "enc_auth_token" (encryptedAccessToken) when authenticate

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).